# Why am I missing the START A BOUNTY button on my question when I am qualified to start a bounty?

Tags: support, bounties

I am trying to start a bounty on [this question](//magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154417/how-to-pull-products-from-a-category-on-an-extra-check-out-step-i-already-have).

As far as I can tell - I am qualified to start bounties (I have done that successfully before):

According to this: magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

I should have all the badges needed and I have 91 reputation points now...

I do have START a BOUNTY button on other questions....

Comment: Are you sure you're logged in to your account already?

Comment: Have you started a bounty on that question before? The only thing that comes to mind is that you started one, it was somehow aborted (e.g. by moderator), so now you need at least 100 points.

Comment: Oh wait... another option is that you posted an answer on the question and deleted it, this also can explain it. (After posting an answer, minimum bounty amount is 100)

Comment: I even did a search (find on the page) for search terms "bounty" and "start" .... could it be there is some kind of an answer on there somewhere (I don't think I did that on purpose) and it's blocking me from being able to start the bounty? To give away 100 reputation points - how many do I have to have?

Comment: To give 100, you must have at least 101.

Comment: @Allysin so you did write an answer there?

Comment: @Allysin Can you check if you have the button now?

Comment: Thank you so much! I just started a 100 point bounty! Thank you - it's working now! :-)

Comment: @Patrick Hofman Thanks - it works now! :-)

Comment: You are welcome. Can you still answer the question from Shadow Wizard about posting an answer? @Allysin

Comment: @Shadow Wizard I never posted an answer on this question because it has NEVER been resolved yet.

Comment: Maybe you did by accident to clarify your question? @Allysin

Comment: @Patrick Hofman It is possible that I could have done it by accident...

Comment: @Allysin you can see your own deleted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "answer" your question, I'm going to <del>steal</del> quote Shadow Wizard's comment on why you can't start a bounty:

> Oh wait... another option is that you posted an answer on the question and deleted it, this also can explain it. (After posting an answer, minimum bounty amount is 100)

This is explained in this [Help Center article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) where it states:

> To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).

In this case, you'll need at least 101 rather than 75 reputation to create the bounty.

Comment: Yeah, but OP never confirmed that. :-/

Comment: @ShadowWizard But the accept is enough right :) ?

Comment: I guess... but better get actual confirmation, e.g. asking user with 10k rep on that site.